# Make a canvas styled in js responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, responsive

I am making a game where you have to erase a colored overlay to reveal an image. the colored cover that you have to erase is styled in JS. I am unable to style this with CSS. I want to make it responsive by working with `%`. But with this JS style it is only possible with `px`. Can someone help me by making a solution where i can style the canvas with `%`.

```js
function createCanvas(parent, width, height) {
    var canvas = {};
    canvas.node = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.context = canvas.node.getContext('2d');
    canvas.node.width = width || 200;
    canvas.node.height = height || 100;
    parent.appendChild(canvas.node);
    return canvas;
}

function init(container, width, height, fillColor) {
    var canvas = createCanvas(container, width, height);
    var ctx = canvas.context;
    // define a custom fillCircle method
    ctx.fillCircle = function(x, y, radius, fillColor) {
        this.fillStyle = fillColor;
        this.beginPath();
        this.moveTo(x, y);
        this.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 10, false);
        this.fill();
    };
    ctx.clearTo = function(fillColor) {
        ctx.fillStyle = fillColor;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    };
    ctx.clearTo(fillColor || "#ddd");

    // bind mouse events
    canvas.node.onmousemove = function(e) {
        if (!canvas.isDrawing) {
           return;
        }
        var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
        var radius = 40; // or whatever
        var fillColor = '#ff0000';
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
        ctx.fillCircle(x, y, radius, fillColor);
    };
    canvas.node.onmousedown = function(e) {
        canvas.isDrawing = true;
    };
    canvas.node.onmouseup = function(e) {
        canvas.isDrawing = false;
    };

    canvas.node.ontouchmove = function(event) {
      for(let index = 0; index < event.touches.length; index++) {
        const touch = event.touches[index];

        const x = touch.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        const y = touch.pageY - this.offsetTop;

        const radius = 40; // or whatever
        const fillColor = '#ff0000';

        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
        ctx.fillCircle(x, y, radius, fillColor);
      }
    };
}

var container = document.getElementById('canvas');
init(container, 400, 400, '#c6bb85');
```

```css
#canvas {
  background-image: url("img/image.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Set the canvas's `.width` and `.height` based on `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`

Comment: You can multiply and percentage value by `offsetWidth/100` or `offsetHeight/100` and you'll get the value in `px`

Comment: @ChrisG could you write it in code for me? I am a beginner at developing and don't really know how to do that.

Comment: @first-dev could you write it in code for me?

Comment: for example, if you want to get the value of `30%` of the canvas width in `px`, you can convert it like so: `v = 30*canvas.offsetWidth/100`

Comment: @Firstdev And where do i have to put that line?

Comment: You could also just use the resize event :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event
and simply put canvas.width=window.innerWidth; canvas.height=window.innerHeight; in it that being if your canvas depends on the width of your window. If not you might still want to have a look.

Comment: @codeanjero is there a change you can put it in a snippet with my code? It would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt to answer your problem with the resize event :

```js
function createCanvas(parent, width, height) {
    var canvas = {};
    canvas.node = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.context = canvas.node.getContext('2d');
    canvas.node.width = width || 200;
    canvas.node.height = height || 100;
    parent.appendChild(canvas.node);
    return canvas;
}

window.onresize=(ev)=>{
//we modify the css property width when the resize is triggered and replace it with the current window size
document.getElementById("canvas").style.width=window.innerWidth+"px";
document.getElementById("canvas").style.height=window.innerHeight+"px";
//if we want the canvas to keep a certain ratio lets say 60%*40% we just have to calculate it (0.6*window.innerWidth) (0.4*window.innerHeight)
}

function init(container, width, height, fillColor) {
    var canvas = createCanvas(container, width, height);
    var ctx = canvas.context;
    // define a custom fillCircle method
    ctx.fillCircle = function(x, y, radius, fillColor) {
        this.fillStyle = fillColor;
        this.beginPath();
        this.moveTo(x, y);
        this.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 10, false);
        this.fill();
    };
    ctx.clearTo = function(fillColor) {
        ctx.fillStyle = fillColor;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    };
    ctx.clearTo(fillColor || "#ddd");

    // bind mouse events
    canvas.node.onmousemove = function(e) {
        if (!canvas.isDrawing) {
           return;
        }
        var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
        var radius = 40; // or whatever
        var fillColor = '#ff0000';
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
        ctx.fillCircle(x, y, radius, fillColor);
    };
    canvas.node.onmousedown = function(e) {
        canvas.isDrawing = true;
    };
    canvas.node.onmouseup = function(e) {
        canvas.isDrawing = false;
    };

    canvas.node.ontouchmove = function(event) {
      for(let index = 0; index < event.touches.length; index++) {
        const touch = event.touches[index];

        const x = touch.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        const y = touch.pageY - this.offsetTop;

        const radius = 40; // or whatever
        const fillColor = '#ff0000';

        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
        ctx.fillCircle(x, y, radius, fillColor);
      }
    };
}

var container = document.getElementById('canvas');
init(container, 400, 400, '#c6bb85');
```

```css
#canvas {
  background-image: url("img/image.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background:deepskyblue;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: It does work, but it might not be what you're looking for :
https://jsfiddle.net/1hsL97av/
I have put it in a jsfiddle where you can resize it and see it's effect.
Maybe you can provide me with more information on how it doesn't work. Is it the pixel ratio ? Is it the way of resizing ? Is there an error in the console ?

Comment: Can i have your discord? I can provide you with more information there in a more easy way.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not how stack overflow works

Comment: Oke i will try to explain it the best i can. But my english and coding skills are not so good haha. in the bottom of the JS you see 
`var container = document.getElementById('canvas');
init(container, 400, 400, '#c6bb85');`

The 400, 400 are now in px. I want to game to work on a phone and ipad so it has to be a bit responsive. I want to use % instead of px. Or i want to use a media query but i don't know how in this case.

Comment: No your english is fine
Media queries also work fine :
https://jsfiddle.net/dwt9Lczs/
But if i understand correctly you are trying to force the canvas to be 400 height and 400 width on all devices so what you want is 40% of the screen to be dedicated to the canvas or that the canvas has the same size on every screen ? You don't want fullscreen? One thing that may be part of the problem is the height, you can not give à height and à width in percent because of the aspect ratio in css, the height will always follow the width unless you give it a fixed size in px.

Comment: I want the colored layer that you have to erase to be 40% of my screen (so 40% witdh and 40% height). But if there is no way to do that a Media querie will work fine. I don't mean the 400px, 400 px in the CSS but at the bottom of the JS. https://jsfiddle.net/s5zxb1mu/ i added a comment on the place i mean.

Comment: well i can only see two things, you either want this :
https://jsfiddle.net/x3qetyv0/
or you want this :
https://jsfiddle.net/x3qetyv0/1/
the first being adjusting the height and width of the canvas from the height and width you give it (400*400)
the second one being a percentage (0.4 which is 40%) of the height and width of the current window you're in 
And in the first case you can always put a check if you want for instance that it never gets bellow 200 canvas.node.width = 0.4*width>200 ? 0.4*width : 200;

Comment: I want canvas to be filled with the colored layer like here  jsfiddle.net/s5zxb1mu but the canvas and the colored layer are both 400, 400px now. And that looks great on a phone, but when i open it on a ipad its small. So i want the canvas (filled with the colored layer) to be a % of my screen. for extra clarity: I want the game to look like this: jsfiddle.net/s5zxb1mu but when you make the window smaller of bigger it just stays 400, 400px. And i want the whole thing to be a bit responsive. So i want the canvas and the colored layer to both get bigger if you make the window bigger.

Comment: Mabey this is a better example: https://jsfiddle.net/a0fqp4z7/ i want this colored layer to be responsive (so that it gets bigger when you make the window bigger). And the best way to do that is with % or a Media querie. But it is styled at the bottom of the JS and i don't know how to style it other than with the (number), (number) in px

Comment: Ok, so your problem is simply that you put your canvas in a div and in order to adapt the canvas to your entire page you have to use the size of your div to scale the canvas :
https://jsfiddle.net/8mekxpwg/

Comment: This is what i mean! Thanks!! The only issue is that the colored layer becomes black when you resize the window.

Comment: Do you know how i can fix that @codeanjero?

Comment: That's a structure problem, which i can't fix, you have to find a way to redraw your canvas each time it is resized. That's why i've put the line 
canvas.context.fillRect(0,0,parent.width, parent.height);
in the onresize event to show it is resized. But just replacing it with init does not work... So i guess you have either to use OOP with static functions or cut the program into functions

Comment: Could you write that in code for me? I really don't know how i could do that. @codeanjero